# RRule and Timezones: skipping next occurrence

Tags: node.js, timezone, luxon, rrule

I'm trying to get the next occurrence from an RRule object (which I store in DB), but no matter what I do, it is always skipping the next occurrence (which should happen on March 20 at 23:50).

[here is a link](https://playcode.io/1807770) to my code.

The output I'm getting is:

```
start date raw:  2024-03-08T23:50:59.000Z
start date from Luxon:  2024-03-08T23:50:59.000Z
current date from Luxon:  2024-03-21T04:11:39.966Z
current date from JS:  2024-03-21T00:11:39.966Z
Next Occurrence raw:  2024-03-21T19:50:59.000Z
Next Occurrence from Luxon:  2024-03-21T23:50:59.000Z
```

which funny enough, is not the same I get from the playground:

```
start date raw: Fri Mar 08 2024 18:50:59 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
start date from Luxon: Fri Mar 08 2024 18:50:59 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
current date from Luxon: Thu Mar 21 2024 00:06:49 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Saving Time)
current date from JS: Wed Mar 20 2024 20:06:49 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Saving Time)
Next Occurrence raw: Thu Mar 21 2024 15:50:59 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Saving Time)
Next Occurrence from Luxon: Thu Mar 21 2024 19:50:59 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Saving Time)
```